# Why can't I move a rectangle using navigation keys in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

Hey guys i'm trying to get my Player class to move when i hit left or right but nothing happens/ I'm new to java and dont really understand why its not working. I have no errors but still nothing happens. Thanks for any help. Also, if you could explain to me why its not working that would be really helpful.

```
import java.awt.Color;
        import java.awt.Dimension;
        import java.awt.EventQueue;
        import java.awt.Graphics;
        import java.awt.Rectangle;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
        import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
        import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
        import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
        import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.Timer;
        import javax.swing.UIManager;
        import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

        public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

            public final static int WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 450;

            public Game game;
            public Player player;

            public GamePanel(Game game) {
                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                this.game = game;
                addKeyListener(this);
                setFocusable(true);
            }
                    public void update() {
                player.update();
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            }

            public void init() {
                System.out.println("!!");
                player = new Player(this, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, getHeight() - 50, getWidth() / 2);
                repaint();
            }


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                update();
                repaint();
            }

            public Player getPlayer(int playerNo) {
                return player;
            }
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            player.pressed(e.getKeyCode());
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            player.released(e.getKeyCode());
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    ;
        }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if (player != null) {
                    player.paint(g);
                }
            }
        }

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Player {

        public static final int WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 50;
        public GamePanel game;
        public int left, right;
        public int y;
        public int x, xa;

        public Player(GamePanel game, int left, int right, int y, int x) {
            this.game = game;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.x = x;
            y = game.getHeight() - HEIGHT;
            x = game.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        public void update() {
            if (x > 0 && x < game.getWidth() - WIDTH) {
                x += xa;
            } else if (x == 0) {
                x++;
            } else if (x == game.getWidth() - WIDTH) {
                x--;
            }
        }

 public void pressed(int keyCode) {
        if (keyCode == left)
            xa = -1;
        else if (keyCode == right)
            xa = 1;
    }

    public void released(int keyCode) {
        if (keyCode == left || keyCode == right)
            xa = 0;
    }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return new Rectangle(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            System.out.println(x + "x" + y);
            g.fillRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `repaint();` statement in the end of the **keyReleased()** method. Irrespective of whether you do something in the **keyTyped()** or **keyPressed()** method, the **keyReleased()** method is always invoked whenever you release the key. So the program control should encounter the repaint() statement here.

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    player.released(e.getKeyCode());
    repaint(); //<--- THIS HERE
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

---

Please also take note of @SasonOhanian's answer and improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have your update and repaint logic in the actionPerformed callback while KeyPressed sets the move variable for player. Debug or print something in your listener methods to see how things are called. I don't think actionPerformed and KeyPressed will be called the way and order you expect them.

Answer (score 0):

Ty for all the help but i needed to make x = x + 1 and x = x -1